# The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following C# that is giving me the error above when trying to parse string to datetime.

```
DateTime backupdate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(imageflowlabel.Text);   
DateTime currentdate = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);    
int result = currentdate.CompareTo(backupdate);
```

`imageflowlable.text` looks like this `2012-04-15 15:23:34:123`

Any ideas on how to convert this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using DateTime.Parse, or even DateTime.ParseExact?

Comment: The default separator for milliseconds is `.` in the Invariant culture, not `:`. But note the suggestions to use parse methods instead of `Convert.ToDateTime`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - use "DateTime.ParseExact()" or "TryParseExact()" with a custom format string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

```
DateTime currentdate;
int result;
try
{
  // EXAMPLE: 2012-04-15 15:23:34:123 
  DateTime backupdate =
     DateTime.ParseExact (
       "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", //mind the casing
       imageflowlabel.Text, 
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  currentdate = System.DateTime.Now.AddHours(-2);    
  result = currentdate.CompareTo(backupdate);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with the time part of your dateTime string.  If your string read "2012-04-15 15:23:34.123" then it would work. You could modify your string and replace the last colon with a period and that would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct; the issue is presumably with your string format, whose last `:` should actually be a `.` (indicating the start of the fractional seconds).

```
Incorrect: 2012-04-15 15:23:34:123
Correct:   2012-04-15 15:23:34.123
```

`Convert.ToDateTime("2012-04-15 15:23:34.123")` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) should work for you, assuming your users have no way of editing that value on their own; in that case, you should use [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044) to unless you want the `FormatException`.

```
var toParse = "2012-04-15 15:23:34:123";

var parsed = DateTime.ParseExact(toParse, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff", null);

Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2012, 4, 15, 15, 23, 34, 123), parsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several answers to resolve the situation outlined in this question such as using DateTime.Parse, DateTime.ParseExact, or Convert.ToDateTime.  I am trying to determine why the problem is seemlingly inconsistent.  I built an application using the Microsoft Enterprise Library Software Factory with a SQL Server 2008 R2 backend and it has been in production for about 9 months now.  It has at least 20 instances with the same code format that assign DateTime property values from C# to System.Data.DBType.DateTime parameters for stored procedures.  19 of the 20 code blocks work fine.  For the 20th I had to add the .ToString() call as shown below to resolve the error mentioned in this question.

```
db.AddInParameter(command, "beginDT", DbType.DateTime, timeBlock.BeginDT.ToString());
```

So anyone have some insight on why would it work fine in 19 absolutely identical instances and not in the 20th?  I am just trying to get more of an understanding of the inter-relationship of these objects so I can build solid code.  I have since gone back to all other instances and added the .ToString() call.  Haven't completed my regression testing though; so, I don't know if that was a mistake.