# how to get equivalent UTC datetime from inapp server response date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, in-app-purchase, utc

I am calling Apple service to verify in app receipt. Below is my service which makes call.

```
 try
        {
            _url =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppleServerUrl"];
            var json = new JObject(
                    new JProperty("receipt-data", receiptToken),
                    new JProperty("password", "mySecretKey")).ToString();

            ASCIIEncoding ascii = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            var request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(_url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                stream.Flush();
            }

            var sendResponse = request.GetResponse();
            string sendResponseText = "";
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(sendResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                sendResponseText = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
            }


            var resObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(sendResponseText.ToString());
            var latestReceipt = resObj["latest_receipt"];
            resObj = (JObject)resObj["latest_receipt_info"].LastOrDefault();

            var expiryDate = Convert.ToDateTime(resObj["expires_date"]);
   }
```

I am getting expiryDate = "2017-05-03 15:08:55 Etc/GMT";

Now I am in need to convert this date to datetime(UTC) & save to my database. While trying to do the same I am getting the error.

> The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 20

While googling I got the below link & tried the stuff mentioned in the link.

- [The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625292/the-string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-there-is-an-unknown-word-star)

  var expiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff",resObj["expires_date"].ToString(),
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

This throws me the below error.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How do I convert the returned date to equivalent UTC Datetime??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the string value by removing the `"Etc"`. There may be a more robust way but this works in a pinch

```
Parse(Regex.Replace("2017-05-03 15:08:55 etc/GMT", "[a-zA-Z]{3}/", ""))
```

which will produce

```
"2017-05-03 15:08:55 GMT"
```

That said, you should definitely be using either `System.DateTimeOffset` or a something like NodaTime. to handle date processing when you are dealing with timezone aware data.